# Call ACTION_VIEW intent from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

My problem seems to be too complex for me :/

I have a main activity like this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

(...)

LinearLayout mainLinearLayout;
mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout);

final JSONObject user = json_user.getJSONObject(0);

ContactListData contactList = new ContactListData();
contactList.AffLayoutData(this, user, mainLinearLayout);
```

I want to inflate elements in the main_activity layout, through ContactListData class.
I want to use a specific class to do that because I have to reuse this contact inflation in another part of my application.

Here my ContactListData.java :

```
public class ContactListData extends Activity {

    public void AffLayoutData(Context context, JSONObject contact, LinearLayout mainLinearLayout) {

        try {

            LinearLayout ll;

            // > Here, a lot of layouts are inflated in main_activity :
            ll = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(context, R.layout.contact_detail_separateur_titre, null);
            ((TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.titre)).setText("Téléphone");

            // (...) blablabla

            // And there are buttons with OnClickListener :

            ((FrameLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.primary_action_view_container)).setOnClickListener(mSMSActionClickListener);
            ((FrameLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.primary_action_view_container)).setTag(contact.getString("Phone"));

            // (...) blablabla
            // Finally, last layout is inflated :
            mainLinearLayout.addView(ll);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("GEDE JSONException", null);
        }
    }

    /** My onClickListener of previous buttons */
    protected final OnClickListener mSMSActionClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", v.getTag().toString(), null)); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

.
All is inflated correctly. But when I click on a button, I have this error :

> 04-28 23:37:51.934: W/dalvikvm(30918): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x41bd3700) 04-28 23:37:51.934:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-28 23:37:51.934:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30918): java.lang.NullPointerException 04-28
>   23:37:51.934: E/AndroidRuntime(30918):    at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
>   04-28 23:37:51.934: E/AndroidRuntime(30918):  at
>   biz.jchambon.gedm.ContactListData$5.onClick(ContactListData.java:302)

I have tried to start Intent.ACTION_VIEW in the parent activity, without success (static/non static problem ...). Who could help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context was wrong.

My ContactListData.class corrected :

```
public class ContactListData extends Activity {

    public Context ParentContext; // < ADDED

    public void AffLayoutData(Context context, JSONObject contact, LinearLayout mainLinearLayout) {

        ParentContext = context; // < ADDED
        LinearLayout ll;

        try {


            // INFLATION ....

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("GEDE JSONException", null);
        }
    }
```

And the OnClickListener intent must be called like this :

```
ParentContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be that `v.getTag()` is `null`.  To get the tag object , the view should already have stored any object.

Looking at your code you have set `onClick` listener for `R.id.primary_action_view_container` view, but have not saved any object as `Tag` for the view.

You should have an object saved as `Tag` for any view like this

```
  view.setTag(yourObject);
```

So , that you can get the object like this

```
 Object yourObject = view.getTag();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ; I had the same idea (I forgot to copy/paste the setTag line). When I do a Log.d("Test getTag", v.getTag().toString()) just before startActivity(intent), I can see it works in the console :/

Comment: I got it, the context was undefined.